# Button sound stops working 

Tags: android, media-player

The problem i have is that my button sound after a while stops working but after a couple more presses returns again.

```
public class custom extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        setContentView(R.layout.nnine);

        final MediaPlayer nnButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jngjgnsj);

        final MediaPlayer mnButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hfh);
```

Comment: Does the button sound stop working and then return again for just bnNext & bnPrevious or bnNine as well?

Comment: What have you already tried to track down the problem so far? What documentation have you checked? Why do you think it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your MediaPlayer instances defined inside of onCreate(). This means that if onCreate() is not called, (ie the activity resumes from being paused), onCreate won't be called and your MediaPlayer instances won't exist. Nor will your button definitions.

Basically, anything you want to persist past the first creation of the activity, you should make a member variable.

You should also `@Override onPause()` so that you can call `nm.stop()` and / or `nn.stop()`.

You should also call `release()` on both and set both to null if they are not already null.

EDIT: define your variables at the top of your activity, not in onCreate() - otherwise they won't survive past that function call:

```
public class CustomActivity extends Activity {

//notice how I've put the button definitions up here, so they live as long as the activity does?
final MediaPlayer clickPlayer1  
final MediaPlayer clickPlayer2
Button this;
Button next;
Button previous;

//etc etc...



}
```

Comment: sorry i am a beginner so not very sure can you give me an wxample if possible? Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger? You should really try that to see what's going on. Put a breakpoint on the line with "startActivity" in it. I'm not sure how you are getting these activities on the same layout, but that's breaking the Activity lifecycle model really badly.  The rule is: 1 Activity per screen (except with tabs, where you can have one per tab). I'd need to see the rest of your project before I could work out what is wrong. Basically, you need to go get an example project from developer.google.com and build your project in the same way.

Comment: I believe I fixed your first issue. What you are seeing is a NEW issue. Instead of not accepting this answer, it would be better to create a new question to fix the new issue. I think that you should take a close look at your code, as I think it, not my answer is really your problem.

Comment: Why don't you want it up anymore?